# Permanent iptables redirect

Tags: iptables, netplan

I have an iptables command I run on Ubuntu 22.04.3 that forwards 443 to 8443. However I have to keep running it every reboot.

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

Only thing I was able to find was adding it to /etc/network/interfaces from 7 years ago which obviously is a bit outdated. Not sure it would work the same way with a netplan yaml.

Comment: I installed iptables-persistent and it grabbed my rules and saved them on install.

Comment: Please move your solution from your comment into an answer

Answer (score 1):

I installed iptables-persistent and it grabbed my rules and saved them on install.